# Html element is getting displayed outside parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place multiple formulas inside a parent container. Each formula object should have close button displayed inside it in the top right corner.

But it seems like there is something wrong with my css. Close button is getting displayed outside parent container.

I am not able to figure it out what really went wrong. I never worked in css before. Please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong here.

```css
.formulaObject {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #4c88aa;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 2px 25px 2px 25px;
  background-color: #D2E9FE;
}

.formulaText {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #4c88aa;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.closeButton {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: -webkit-calc(10px);
}

.formulaDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.2);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #4c88aa;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulaDiv">
  <div class="formulaObject">
    <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
    <div class="closeButton">x</div>
    <div>
      <div class="formulaObject">
        <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
        <div class="closeButton">x</div>
        <div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved formatting of your HTML, div wasn't closing properly and use `positioning` to position close button.

```css
.formulaObject {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #4c88aa;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 2px 25px 2px 25px;
    background-color: #D2E9FE;
    position: relative;
}

.formulaText {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #4c88aa;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.closeButton {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.formulaDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.2);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #4c88aa;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulaDiv">
  <div class="formulaObject">
    <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
    <div class="closeButton">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="formulaObject">
    <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
    <div class="closeButton">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cool! This is perfect. Could you please tell me what was going wrong?

Comment: `<div>` wasn't closing properly you can check in your HTML, and I have used `position:absolute` to `.closeButton` relatively to `.formulaObject ` to position it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your line height for `.formulaObject` is set to 50px and inherited by the button text, but you set the height of the black button to 20px. You can fix this by setting the line height within that button to 20px as well.

```css
.formulaObject {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 250 px;
  border - radius: 5 px;
  border: 2 px solid #4c88aa;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 2px 25px 2px 25px;
  background-color: # D2E9FE;
}

.formulaText {
  font-size: 15 px;
  color: #4c88aa;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.closeButton {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: -webkit-calc(10px);
}

.formulaDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.2);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid # 4 c88aa;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulaDiv">
  <div class="formulaObject">
    <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
    <div class="closeButton">x</div>
    <div>
      <div class="formulaObject">
        <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
        <div class="closeButton">x</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check updated snippet below:

```css
 .formulaObject{
     float : left;
     display : block;
     width : 250px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     border: 2px solid #4c88aa;
     height : 50px;
     line-height:50px;
     margin : 2px 25px 2px 25px;
     background-color: #D2E9FE;
     position: relative;
     }
     .formulaText{
     font-size:15px;
     color:#4c88aa;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align:left;
     margin-left:10px;
     width:150px;
     }
     .closeButton{
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: 5px;
     top : 0;
     right: 0;
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     border-radius: 3px;
     width : 10px;
     height: 20px;
     width: -webkit-calc(10px);
     position: absolute;
     line-height: 1;
     }
     .formulaDiv{
     width: 300px;
     height: 500px;
     background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.2);
 
     border : 1px solid #4c88aa; 
     }
```

```html
  <div class="formulaDiv">
  <div class="formulaObject">
  <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
  <div class="closeButton">x</div>
  </div>

  <div class="formulaObject">
  <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
  <div class="closeButton">x</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yeah...this is cool. Why these div elements are not properly aligned?

Comment: @Madhusudan your `div` was not closed properly, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.formulaObject {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #4c88aa;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 2px 25px 2px 25px;
  background-color: #D2E9FE;
}

.formulaText {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #4c88aa;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.closeButton {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: -webkit-calc(10px);
}

.formulaDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.2);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #4c88aa;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulaDiv">
  <div class="formulaObject">
    <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
    <div class="closeButton">x</div>
    <div>
      <div class="formulaObject">
        <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
        <div class="closeButton">x</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you had mulitple element tag validation errors. line-height:50px; was also causing the x's to be out of their little black box. Here is how I fixed it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <style>
         .formulaObject{
         float : left;
         display : block;
         width : 250px;
         border-radius: 5px;
         border: 2px solid #4c88aa;
         height : 50px;
         margin : 2px 25px 2px 25px;
         background-color: #D2E9FE;
         }
         .formulaText{
         font-size:15px;
         color:#4c88aa;
         font-weight: bold;
         text-align:left;
         margin-left:10px;
         width:150px;
         }
         .closeButton{
         margin-top: 0px;
         margin-right: 5px;
         top : 0;
         right: 0;
         background-color: black;
         color: white;
         text-align: center;
         border-radius: 3px;
         width : 10px;
         height: 20px;
         width: -webkit-calc(10px);
         float: right;
         }
         .formulaDiv{
         width: 300px;
         height: 500px;
         background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.2);
         overflow-x: hidden;
         overflow-y: auto;
         border : 1px solid #4c88aa;
         overflow:auto;
         }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="formulaDiv">
      <div class="formulaObject">
      <div class="closeButton">x</div>
      <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
      </div>
      <div class="formulaObject">
        <div class="closeButton">x</div>
      <p class="formulaText">Cost = 0.5 * Weight </p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```